# What is the difference between "will", "be going to" and present continuous when expressing something in the future?

Tags: difference, future-constructions

Are all of these sentences grammatically correct? Have all of them exactly the same meaning?

1. Anita **is taking** an English exam tomorrow.
2. Anita **is going to take** an English exam tomorrow.
3. Anita **will take** an English exam tomorrow.

In the "*languagetool.org*" it says: "will is more commonly used with recent decisions, certain futures, and predictions. Going to tends to be used about events that were previously decided on."

I think this sentence is a certain future so I should use "**will**", but also I think it is previously decided on so I can probably use "**going to**" as well.

In the "*bbc.com*" it says:

- **Will** often expresses the future as fact – so it's used for very strong opinions or predictions.
- **Be going to** is used for something you want to do.
- The **present continuous** is used for arrangements. It's very similar to going to for intention.

So I think this sentence has all of these conditions and I guess I can use them interchangeably without any differences in their meanings.

Comment: There are many ways to express the future in an example like this. You can use any of the following:  takes, is to take, is taking, will take, will be taking, is going to take, is going to be taking.  You can also use: has an exam tomorrow, or sits an exam tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most contexts, *I am going to [verb]* and *I will [verb]* are interchangeable. Sometimes the former *may* place more emphasis on the fact of your ***current*** intention/expectation, where the latter emphasises the ***future*** action.

There are some contexts where the difference is clear, and this may have some bearing on why OP thinks there's a *planned/spontaneous* distinction (usually there isn't). Say you're round a friend's house watching a football match on TV, and at half-time the beer runs out...

> You: *"I'll nip down the shop and get some more beer."*
>
> Friend: *"It's raining - I'll find my umbrella for you."*

If you reply *"Don't bother - I'm going to use my car"*, the implication is you had already decided you were going to use the car before you first said you'd get the beer. But if you say *"Don't bother - I will use my car"*, this implies you just made that decision in response to what your friend said.

---

Thanks to [Peter Shor](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87900/going-to-vs-will#comment176480_87900) over on ELU for flagging up another context...

> *"Be careful!...*
> *...it's **going to** bite!"*
> *...it **will** bite!"*

...where native speakers often make a distinction. In this context, *going to* usually signifies *immediate* danger (it's just about to bite), but *will* can just mean *it's bitten others before, and will/may bite you soon if you're not careful* (effectively, the same as *"Careful! It bites!"* where present tense indicates "habitual" action).